# calabash-ios: The app hangs when running automation

Tags: ios, ruby, ios-simulator, calabash, calabash-ios

I'm using the simulator (iOS 9.0).

I’m running the command: `device_target=UDID cucumber`

The simulator starts and the app is loading, but then the console hang for few min until time out.

I have the same issue when I run it manually in the console:

```
calabash-ios console

start_test_server_in_background
```

The error that I get is:

```
#<RuntimeError: Timed out connecting to Calabash server after 10 retries. Make sure it is linked and App isn't crashing>
RuntimeError: Unable to make connection to Calabash Server at http://localhost:37265/`
Make sure you don't have a firewall blocking traffic to http://localhost:37265/.
```

running the command `curl http://localhost:37265` and get the error - `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 37265: Connection refused`

what I’m missing?

(the app developed in Xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

> device_target=UDID cucumber

This is not doing what you expect.  Calabash responds to DEVICE_TARGET not device_target.

My best guess is that you need to check whether your .app is linked with Calabash.

Please see these two pages:

- https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems
- https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version#what-version-of-the-server-is-embedded-in-my-app